# How to include endTime property in a Quartz Scheduler(Simple Trigger)?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

```
<bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="rabbitJob" />
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="1" />
    </bean>
```

How to incorporate something like:
            **`<property name="endTime" value="50" />`**

So the quartz scheduler stops executing after 50 ms?

I tried the above property, but I am getting errors. Not able to find any tutorials about the same.

Answer (score -1):

endTime is an absolute date and time, just as startTime is - so "50" as a value doesn't make sense - you need date and time.

Comment: How to incorporate it as a property?